# How to access a reference application

Tags: .net, reference

I have installed an application that uses .net framework 3.5
after setup I can't find the exe file, when select properties it says it's a reference
How can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're deploying the application using ClickOnce, it's being installed in a temp folder.
Maybe you will find it somewhere like this:

> c:\Documents and  Settings\user-name\Local  Settings\Apps\2.0\temp\temp\temp\app.exe

where "temp" is some random folder name.

So, try searching in your

> c:\Documents and Settings\user-name\Local Settings\Apps\2.0

folder.
Good luck!